# Flyway-Jenkins Build Locations not working

Tags: jenkins, flyway

I'm getting the below error when I gave the sql file location in the flyway plugin in jenkins.

If i give empty location it's working fine. It's automatically taking the default sql path.

If i give a specific location i'm getting the below error.

Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flyway_test
$ /flyway/flyway -user=root ******** -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1 -locations=/flyway/sql/ migrate Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse

Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1 (MySQL 5.6)
WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:flyway/sql
WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:flyway/sql
WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:flyway/sql
WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:flyway/sql
Successfully validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.028s)
Current version of schema `test1`: 2
ERROR: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
ERROR: Build step 'Invoke Flyway' failed due to errors.
Finished: FAILURE
[flyway input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7lls.png)

[output getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpUl2.png)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the description of the `location` field in your configuration dialog. It says the same as it's said about the `location` parameter in the [flyway documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate)

> The location type is determined by its prefix.
>   Unprefixed locations or locations starting with classpath: point to a package on the classpath and may contain both sql and java-based migrations.
>
> Locations starting with filesystem: point to a directory on the filesystem and may only contain sql migrations.

That means, that you are providing the path within classpath, since you didn't add the prefix. If you want to add some filesystem resources, you need to specify it this way:

```
filesystem:/flyway/sql/
```